# Using Shopify's themekit to deploy via codeship

Tags: shopify, codeship

Hi I'm looking to use codeship to deploy my master branch to my production shopify store.

How would i setup `themekit` so it would be available on my pipeline ?

Installing themekit involves sudo :

`curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shopify/themekit/master/scripts/install | sudo python`

or homebrew `brew install themekit`

Both of which to the extent of my knowledge is not possible on codeship